# Error with Temperature for SEBAL

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to create a layer of surface temperature for SEBAL model. I am using the standard model for   LST for Landsat 8. When I run the code the following error occurs: **Temperature: Layer error: ImageCollection.mosaic: ***Error in map(ID=LC08_159042_20210106):
Number.log, argument 'input': Invalid type.
Expected type: Number.
Actual type: Image<[Enb]>.*****

```
function addLST(image) {
  var Rc = image.select('ST_B10').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0);
  var K1 = ee.Image.constant(774.8853);
  var K2 = ee.Image.constant(1321.0789);
  var t0 = ee.Number(image.select('Enb').multiply(K1).divide(Rc).add(1)).log();
  var t1 = K1.divide(t0).rename('Temperature');
  return image.addBands(t1);
  
} 
var filtered=filtered.map(addLST);  
Map.addLayer(filtered.select('Temperature'), {palette : ['blue','pink','brown','orange','yellow','green']}, 'Temperature');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the 'system:index' of image in error message and, I found out the exact product id that you are using: LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1/LC08_159042_20210106. If you didn't rename band for obtaining LST, this is 'B10'; not 'ST_B10'. On the other hand, RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_10 is 0.1; not 149 as it is in your code snippet.

Taking above considerations, I modified your code as follows by using a more intuitive approach with expressions.

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1')
  .filterMetadata('system:index', 'equals', 'LC08_159042_20210106');

var image = dataset.first();

print(image);

print('RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_10',image.get('RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_10'));
print('RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_10',image.get('RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_10'));
print('K1_CONSTANT_BAND_10',image.get('K1_CONSTANT_BAND_10'));
print('K2_CONSTANT_BAND_10',image.get('K2_CONSTANT_BAND_10'));

Map.centerObject(image);
Map.addLayer(image);

function addLST(image) {
  var Rc = image.expression(
    'L*0.0003342 + 0.1', 
    {'L': image.select('B10')});

  var t1 = image.expression(
    '(1321.0789 / log (774.8853 / Rc + 1)) - 273.15',
    {'Rc': Rc}).rename('Temperature');

  return image.addBands(t1);
  
}

var parVis = {"opacity":1,
                 "bands":["Temperature"],
                 "min":12.563630937215294,
                 "max":29.057135926564285,
                 "palette":['blue','pink','brown','orange','yellow','green']};

var filtered = dataset.map(addLST); 

print(filtered);

Map.addLayer(filtered.select('Temperature'), parVis, 'Temperature');
```

After running above [code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/a2886c9101690fb8f6e660ac730a1c09) in GEE code editor, I got result of following picture without any problem:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your elaborate answer. I wanted to use this for the whole image collection for UAE to create SEBAL model for the year 2021. I used aforementioned scaling factors taken from    this place: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/LANDSAT_LC08_C02_T1_L2#bands. And regarding the t1 formula: why are you subtracted 273.15? because for LST for outgoing radiation there is a different formula.

Comment: 1) Above code can map whatever image collection for obtaining LST in each image. Only use adequate name. 2) Document in the link has **add** factor wrong. I corroborated that in other sources and printed all factors involved in my question code.  **RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_10** is 0.1; not 149.0. 3)   The number 273.15 is for converting ºK to ºC. If you want temperatures in Kelvin degrees only delete it.

Comment: You missed Enb and put log instead of ln. Is it deliberately?

Comment: I didn't miss Enb because I 'm calculating brightness temperature, You missed the formula for calculating Enb so, you should adapt that for LST calculation. On the other hand, you should know that in GEE natural logarithm is log; not ln (you used it in your question). Logarithm with base 10 is log10.